# Local addresses beginning with 127 not accessible via internet?

Tags: ip

I am not running a firewall on Ubuntu 23.04.  Is it safe to assume that the only ports I have accessible via the internet are 443, 80, and 22?

```
netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is a classic basic networking question. A Google search will provide you an immediate, clear answer: 127.*.*.* addresses are reserved for loopback interfaces, accessible by the local machine only and not routable.

Comment: @user535733, I didn't know what to search for, but thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For internet related stuff your first choice for information might be the [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/). In this case [RFC5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) deals among other topics with local host addresses.

For your second question:

- Ports 80 and 443 are accessible via IPv4.
- Ports 22, 80 and 443 are accessible via IPv6.
- All other ports are only accessible from your own IP instance (aka local host).

Cheers!
Joerg